# Search criteria language parser in Python?

Tags: python, django, parsing, django-rest-framework

I am writing a web app with Django and [DjangoRestFramework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) for an internal app for my school. It is a replacement for a very old homegrown app written in Microsoft Access 2003. One of the functionalities that my users would very much like to have is to be able to search a field (e.g. `donation_amount` in a `donation`table) not only by the exact amount but with a query such as this:

```
< 130 and > 125
```

Access currently allows this sort of functionality and it is very useful, however I am completely unaware of a way to implement anything like this without inserting their queries directly into SQL (extremely dangerous) or using `eval` in a Python expression (even more dangerous).

Are there any libraries or sub-languages which would permit this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Django's ecosystem, but the Python standard library contains `ast.parse`, which parses a valid Python expression string and produces an abstract syntax tree, which you can dissect and translate into a query - or a serie of function calls, or whatever you need. So if you can't find anything more specific, then this might be of use.

This code:

```
ast.parse('donation_amount < 130 and donation_amount > 125')
```

returns the following AST structure:

```
ast.Module(
  ast.Expr([
    ast.BoolOp(ast.And(), [
      ast.Compare(
        [ast.Lt()],
        ast.Name('donation_amount', ast.Load()),
        [ast.Num(130)]),
      ast.Compare(
        [ast.Gt()],
        ast.Name('donation_amount', ast.Load()),
        [ast.Num(125)])])]))
```

So that takes care of the parsing, but you'll still need to translate that into a query of your own. But it looks like you only need to handle a small number of node types:

```
BoolOp -> and, or
Compare -> ==, !=, >, <, >=, <=, in, not in
Name -> identifiers (column names, true/false/null, etc.)
Num -> numbers
Str -> strings
```

And perhaps `ast.Call` nodes, if you want to support database functions, and `ast.Tuple` or `ast.List` nodes, if you want to support `IN` functionality. If the AST contains any other node types you can reject it as an invalid query.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Django ORM to model the database? If so then wouldn't it come down to:

```
 Donation.objects.filter(donation_amount__lte=130).filter(donation_amount__gte=125)
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct, it is that simple. However, the question is how to parse a string (safely) into something that I can recognize in code and then turn into the Django code that you have shown.